# concrete5 ccm_activateTabBar() not defined when not logged in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, concrete5

I have a specific question, I did build a component with tabs in concrete5 v8 with this tutorial:

[Creating tabbed panels in concrete5](https://documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/using-tabbed-panels-in-concrete5-5-7)

It worked just fine, as long as I was logged in into concrete5, as soon as I am not logged in I get the following error in the console, and therefor I'm not able to click on the different tabs:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ccm_activateTabBar is not defined
>      at HTMLDocument. (entsorgung-von-abfaellen:84)
>      at j (jquery.js:2)
>      at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
>      at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
>      at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2)

The error references to this part of the line 84:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() { ccm_activateTabBar($('#ccm-tabs-1077221103'));});</script>
```

which follows directly after the ul element and seems to got generated by concrete5.

I was not able to find anything related at all, I guess it has something to do with missing assets that are only loaded when logged in as administrator.

I'm currently only loading the following assets when not logged in:

```
$u = new User();
if(!$u->isLoggedIn()) {
  $this->requireAsset('javascript', 'jquery');
  $this->requireAsset('jquery/ui');
}
```

Maybe someone already worked with the concrete5 tabs and can help me with this error.

Comment: The concrete5 UI components are meant to be used in the dashboard pages, or when a user is logged in and edits the site.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to use them otherwise? Just asking before I refactor my component with own custom code.

Comment: Of course you can hack concrete5 and use them. But I wouldn't do that: you can use one of the many toolkit out there, like jQueryUI.

Answer (score 0):

Ass suggested by Michele Locati, you should probably use jquery/ui or bootstrap components to build you tab component.

But if you find yourself in the same situation as I was, a very simple fix is to copy the tabs.js from

> concrete/js/build/core/app/tabs.js

to your theme folder and include it if the user is not logged in.

For example like this:

```
<?php
$u = new User();
if(!$u->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
  <script src="<?php echo $view->getThemePath(); ?>/js/c5_tabs/tabs.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The tabs.js is part of app.js which is quite big, so I only used tabs.js, which only contains the needed function I was missing.

Credits for this information to MrKDilkington from the [concrete5 forum](https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/ccm_activatetabbar-not-defined-when-not-logged-in):